# Custom jQuery slider image calculation

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using some code for a jQuery image slider that I found to work with a custom post type in wordpress(pods). The slider is working perfectly, but I need to limit the number of times a user can scroll to the next image based on how many images there are.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() {
$("img.enlarge").live('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var src = this.src;
   $("#fullImage").attr("src", src);
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {

$('img').filter(function(index){return $(this).attr('src')==='';}).removeClass('enlarge');
$('img').filter(function(index){return $(this).attr('src')==='';}).hide(); 

var $item = $('img.enlarge'), //Cache your DOM selector
    visible = 1, //Set the number of items that will be visible
    index = 0, //Starting index
    endIndex = ( $item.length / visible ) ; //End index (NOTE:: Requires visible to be a factor of $item.length... You can improve this by rounding...)

    $('div#arrowR').click(function(){
        if(index < endIndex ){
          index++;
          $item.animate({'left':'-=275px'});
      }
  });

    $('div#arrowL').click(function(){
        if(index > 0){
          index--;            
          $item.animate({'left':'+=275px'});
      }
  });

});
</script>

<div class="detail-slider-thumbs" id="detail-images">
 <img class="enlarge" src="{@main_image}"/>
 <img class="enlarge" src="{@image_2}"/>
 <img class="enlarge" src="{@image_3}"/>
 <img class="enlarge" src="{@image_4}"/>
 <img class="enlarge" src="{@image_5}"/>
</div>
```

So, if the user only uploads 4 images, I need the code to dynamically respond to that number and not just scroll to a blank image spot like it currently does.

Comment: And what about it is not working? Seems like you already have that limit?

Comment: Let's say there are only 4 images loaded, the user can continue clicking the next arrow until there are no images in view and the user is just clicking through nothing, so if they click to scroll to the right 20 times they will have to scroll back to the left 20 times before they see any images.

Comment: But you already set an if statement for both directions. How can they scroll any further?